# variable value not changing inside axios then method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
let found = false;
axios
   .get(link)
   .then((response) => {
      response.data.map((element) => {
         if (element.id_ticket.toString() === nbTicket) found = true;
      });
      console.log(found);
   });
```

so im trying to get data from the api and see if the value of 'nbTicket' is in the returned data and that is done using the 'found' variable so if i log the 'found' variable value outside the .then method it stays false even if the value exists and when i do it iside the .then methods it gives the correct value

```
let found = false;
axios
   .get(link)
   .then((response) => {
      response.data.map((element) => {
         if (element.id_ticket.toString() === nbTicket) found = true;
      });
   });
   console.log(found);
```

Comment: nbTicket is a string or variable ?

Comment: the console.log outside the then prints before the axios request happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your supposed to use async/await strategy, because console.log happens after Axios request:

```
async function getNbTicket(){
  let found = false;
  const { data } = await axios.get(link);
     data.data.map((element) => {
     if (element.id_ticket.toString() === nbTicket) found = true;
  });
  return found; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your console.log(found); is executing is executing before you fetch data from api
you can call it inside then or use async await if you want to call console.log(found); after you get data from api

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior, because of the async and sync.

you have two options
first one is to wrap your code inside a async function

```
const checkIfTicketIsFound = async () => {
  let found = false;
  const { data } = await axios.get(link);
  data.map((element) => {
    if (element.id_ticket.toString() === nbTicket) found = true;
  })
  console.log(found)
  return found
}
```

Or

you need to print inside the then chain

```
    let found = false;
    axios
       .get(link)
       .then((response) => {
          response.data.map((element) => {
             if (element.id_ticket.toString() === nbTicket) found = true;
          });
console.log(found);
       });
```